# Error: premature close. What's the problem?

Tags: gulp

I'm making a website, I decided to use gulp, I did it clearly according to the tutorial, everything is the same, but for some reason I don't want to work, tell me what's wrong?

ERROR in terminal:

```
[17:20:24] Using gulpfile C:\projects\basic-telematics\gulpfile.js
[17:20:24] Starting 'styles'...
[17:20:24] 'styles' errored after 82 ms
[17:20:24] Error: premature close
    at onclosenexttick (C:\projects\basic-telematics\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:53:86)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

gulpfile.js:

```
const {src, dest} = require('gulp')


const scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))


function styles() {
    return src('#source/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(scss())
        .pipe(dest('css/style.min.css'))
}



exports.styles = styles;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought the screenshot would go, since the information from the photo will not be copied to the IDE, already fixed...

Answer (score 0):

`gulp.dest` needs to be given the name of the target **directory**, not the file name.

Replace

```
.pipe(dest('css/style.min.css'))
```

with

```
.pipe(dest('css'))
```

It would be nice if the gulp framework provides an error message like "the folder Css/style.min.css cannot be created because a file exists with the same name", instead of "Error: premature close".

Answer (score -1):

Please find this [gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate) repo.
You might find what you need

Comment: Why do I need your boiler-plate code?)

Comment: you mentioned that you decided to use gulp, and that you did it clearly according to the tutorial, and looks like you might want to look at other running gulp-files.
I'm used to do that to gain more experience looking at other peoples code.
any way forgive me for offering :)
also you might want to remove the hash in your src 
return src('#source/scss/style.scss')

Comment: I've used it before, just now this version doesn't work on any of my computers, different versions of windows, different versions of node.js and no one can help me with this problem, as if vs code is broken for the new gulp, or node.js, the author of the video two weeks ago, everything works fine, asked a good friend, said the code is correct, then what is the reason?

Comment: If you have your repo public on github,, I might help

Comment: I solved this problem, I just didn't want to overwrite the file, deleted style.min.css and everything became fine

Comment: that is very good, wish you best coding :)